# How to make a booklike page using article class?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, header-footer, article

I'm writing some class notes in TeX and I would like to customize the page to make it look more like a book page, with those upper bars in the chapter, as shown in the template below.

[image: les]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,breaklinks=true,backref=true,linkcolor=black,colorlinks=true]%
{hyperref}%
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}
%TCIDATA{OutputFilter=latex2.dll}
%TCIDATA{Version=5.50.0.2953}
%TCIDATA{LastRevised=Friday, December 14, 2018 09:04:09}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="GraphicsSave" CONTENT="32">}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="SaveForMode" CONTENT="1">}
%TCIDATA{BibliographyScheme=Manual}
%BeginMSIPreambleData
\providecommand{\U}[1]{\protect\rule{.1in}{.1in}}
%EndMSIPreambleData
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm} \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0cm} \setlength{\textheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16.5cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            %\tiny,\small,\large,\Large,\LARGE, \huge,\Huge,\HUGE
            { \Large \sc Universidade Federal do Maranhão}
            \vskip 0.5cm
            { \Large \sc Centro de Ciências Exatas e Tecnologia}
            \vskip 0.5cm {\Large  \sc Departamento de Física}
            \vskip 6cm
            \begin{sloppypar}
                {\Large Lei de Faraday (Indução eletromagnética)  \bf \\ }\end{sloppypar}
            \vskip 4cm
            \vfill
            {\sc\large NOME: Matheus Rodrigues Linhares Guimarães \hfill }
            \vskip 0.05cm
            {\sc\large Curso: Física \hfill }
            \vskip 0.05cm
            {\sc\large Matrícula: 2017016968 \hfill }
            \vfill
            \vskip 0.05cm
            {\sc 29 de Novembro de 2018}
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}


    \begin{titlepage}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{titlepage}

\newpage

\section{Introdução}

A indução eletromagnética foi descoberta de forma independente por
\textit{Michael Faraday} em 1831 e \textit{Joseph Henry} em 1832. Faraday, no
entanto, foi o primeiro a publicar os resultados de seus experimentos. Em 29
de agosto de 1831, data da primeira demonstração experimetal da indução
eletromagnética feita por Faraday, ele amarrou dois fios em lados opostos de
um anel de ferro $\left(  \text{ou toro, um arranjo similar a um transformador
    toroidal moderno}\right)  $. Face às recém-descobertas propriedades do
eletromagnetismo , ele esperava que, quando a corrente começasse a passar em
um fio, uma espécie de onde viajaria através do anel e causaria algum efeito
elétrico no lado oposto. Conectou, então, um dos fios a um galvanômetro e o
outro a uma bateria. Foi observada, de fato, uma corrente trasiente - que ele
chamou de "onda de eletricidade" - nos momentos em que conectou e desconectou
o fio à bateria. Esta indução ocorreu devido à mudança que houve no fluxo
magnético quando a bateria foi conectada e desconectada.

Faraday explicou a indução eletromagnética usando um conceito que chamou de
\textit{linhas de força}. No entanto, grande parte dos cientistas da época
rejeitaram suas ideias teóricas, principalmente porque não havia uma
formulação matemática para elas. \textit{James Clerk Maxwell, }contudo, usou
as ideias de Faraday como base para sua teoria eletromagnética quantitativa.
Nos estudos de Maxwell, o aspecto da \textit{variabilidade} com o tempo da
indução eletromagnética é expressado como uma equação diferencial, a qual
\textit{Olivier Heaviside }referiu-se como a lei de Faraday, embora seja
diferente da versão original da lei de Faraday. A versão de Heaviside é a
forma que hoje é reconhecida como parte do grupo de equações conhecidas como
\textbf{equações de Maxwell.}

A lei de Lenz, formulada por \textit{Heinrich Lenz }em 1834, descreve o "fluxo
\ através do circuito", e fornece a direção da força eletromotriz e corrente
induzidas resultantes da indução eletromagnética.
\end{document}
```

Comment: First thing would be to change your class to be more suited for a book rather than an article. Try `book` instead of `article`.

Comment: I already tried to change the class, but I did not succeed. Not to mention that he changed the presentation of the text a little.

Comment: If you want to write a fancy chapter heading with the horizontal bars, the right-aligned chapter number and chapter name, and the spacing between the chapter heading and the main text, I highly recommend using the `titlesec` package and using the `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` macros to define the chapter heading.  At the end of [the documentation](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) are a few examples for redefined section headings and chapter headings.  I'll write up a proper answer momentarily.

Comment: As @Johannes_B said, switch your document class to `book` class instead of an `article`. Afterwards, LaTeX allows you to custom your chapters with `titlesec` package or, in an easier way with `fncychap` who setup your heading's chapters with the choosen option. See [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fncychap/fncychap.pdf). I recommend you to try in your preamble : `\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}`

Answer (score 5):

First, you should use a book-like document class to use `\chapter` instead of \section as first level headings. Then you can customize the chapter style with the  package `tilesec` in the standard book class or alternatively according the document class commands for this purpose.

For example, using `memoir` you have already defined some chapter styles as "madsen" that is similar to the showed in the question:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\chapterstyle{madsen}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduç\~ao}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

And you can define others as well. Run `texdoc memoir` an see "6.5.1 Defining a chapter style". There are also a showcase of all defined chapter styles in this manual.

Answer (score 4):

With the `titlesec` package you can redefine any of your headings very precisely to provide the format/layout you like.  Since that top rule is so close to the page number and since the page number is in the header despite being the start of a chapter, you might want to use the `fancyhdr` package and redefine the `plain` pagestyle to get the top rule and the page number up top.

With both of these in mind, here is an approximation of the chapter heading in your image.  By consulting the [the `titlesec` documentation](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf), you can modify this to more exactly match your desired chapter header.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[OR,EL]{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{2cm}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\huge\bfseries} %format of label and text
    {\filleft\LARGE\chaptertitlename\space\Huge\thechapter} %label definition
    {0pt} %separation between label and title
    {\titlerule\filleft} %code before title
    [] %code after body

\chapter{Example}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Approximation of desired header and heading]

Comment: +1 but there are not enough emphasis in "the header despite being the start of a chapter". Is not enough clear where you are if there are a huge title in the page? The header here only steal the space to highlight the chapter title.